# Switching the location of x and y axes for a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making 3D graphs using Matplotlib and noticed that the default is that the "left side" is the y axis and the right is the x axis, and was wondering if I could switch those. Here's the code and image I've made:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-3, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-3, 5)
ax.set_zlim(-3, 5)
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=32)

# u
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 2, -1, 0, color='C0', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, label=r'$\vec{u}$')
plt.plot([2, 2], [0, -1], 'k--', linewidth=1)
plt.plot([0, 2], [-1, -1], 'k--', linewidth=1)

# v
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, -1, 2, -1, color='C1', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, label=r'$\vec{v}$')
ax.plot([0, -1], [2, 2], [0, 0], 'k--', linewidth=1)
ax.plot([-1, -1], [0, 2], [0, 0], 'k--', linewidth=1)
ax.plot([-1, -1], [2, 2], [0, -1], 'k--', linewidth=1)

# w
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 2, color='C2', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, label=r'$\vec{w}$')
ax.plot([0, 0], [-1, -1], [0, 2], 'k--', linewidth=1)
ax.plot([0, 0], [-1, 0], [2, 2], 'k--', linewidth=1)

# b
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, color='C3', arrow_length_ratio=0.2, label=r'$\vec{b}$', linewidth=3)

plt.legend()
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize='large')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize='large')
ax.set_zlabel(r'$z$', fontsize='large')
ax.quiver(-3, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, color='k', arrow_length_ratio=0.05) # x-axis
ax.quiver(0, -3, 0, 0, 8, 0, color='k', arrow_length_ratio=0.05) # y-axis
ax.quiver(0, 0, -3, 0, 0, 8, color='k', arrow_length_ratio=0.05) # z-axis

plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]

As you can see the y-axis is on the left, and the x on the right. Is there a way for me to switch these?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you input `y` into `x` and vice versa? then you can label the x-axis with `y` and the y-axis with `x`

Comment: Yes, that method also occurred to me to just invert the inputs. But I was wondering if there was any other way to switch them while keeping everything else normal.

Comment: Sorry, I looked a bit but couldn't find a built in, but maybe someone else will know...

Comment: No worries I also spent a lot of time looking and couldn't find anything, which is why I posted here hoping someone will know. :)

Comment: I guess you may just rotate your 3d plot with `ax.view_init(elevation, azimuth)`.

Comment: @Poolka Thanks for the suggestion, I've also tried doing that but I noticed that rotating it brings the entire plot (i.e. the axes and everything) along with it, resulting in something that I initially did not want. I was just wondering if it was simple enough to switch the default positioning of the axes, but it seems that there is nothing like that. At least not yet.

Comment: It is not clear what's your goal. Axes are connected with the data in the figure. It is important. You wanna just switch `x` and `y` like literally swap the letters? Then change axis' names - `ax.set_xlabel('Y')`, `ax.set_ylabel('X')`.

Comment: Let me give you an example. The blue arrow in the graph has coordinates (2, -1, 0). That's why it's pointing in the "left" direction (I don't know how better to explain it, so please bear with me). However, if I were to switch the x and the y-axes, the arrow would be pointing in the "right" direction with the same coordinates, with everything else being the same.

Comment: I still don't get what you wanna achieve. Actual axes swap changes coordiante system orientation (from right hand to left hand). Then you have to switch both coordinate order and axes titles kinda manually because matplotlib does not support coordinate system orientation. Maybe you facing XY problem? Or maybe you simply causing yourself some extra trouble out of nothing?